# passing lambda to void specified template fails

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, std-function

i simplified the problem as much as i could so here is the function in question:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void ExecuteFunction(std::function<void(T)> f)
    {
    }
};
```

if i call the function with int-typing everything works fine, however, if i call it with a void-typed lambda it doesn't compile anymore.

```
Test test;

test.ExecuteFunction<void>(    // doesn't compile
    [](void)->void
{
    int i = 5;
});

test.ExecuteFunction<int>(    // this compiles
    [](int)->void
{
    int i = 5;
});
```

Compiler errors:

```
Error   C2672   'Test::ExecuteFunction': no matching overloaded function found  
Error   C2770   invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'void Test::ExecuteFunction(std::function<void(P)>)'  
Error (active)      no instance of function template "Test::ExecuteFunction" matches the argument list
```

is there a way around this? how would someone specify the template so that both calls work?

Comment: `void` isnt the type of a parameter that you could pass to a function. `std::function<void(T)>` takes exactly one parameter of type `T`, while your first lambda takes exactly zero parameters

Comment: Here is the related proposal [P0146](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0146r1.html). Interesting to read if you have time to spent I guess :) No idea what its current status is, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is too late to play?

I propose another solution based on a custom type trait (with a specialization for `void`) that, given a `T` type, define the correct `std::function` `type`; i mean

```
template <typename T>
struct getFuncType
 { using type = std::function<void(T)>; };

template <>
struct getFuncType<void>
 { using type = std::function<void()>; };
```

This way your `ExecuteFunction()` simply become

```
template <typename T>
void ExecuteFunction (typename getFuncType<T>::type f)
{
}
```

If you want simplify a little the use of `getFuncType`, you can add a `using` helper to extract the `type`

```
template <typename T>
using getFuncType_t = typename getFuncType<T>::type;
```

so the `ExecuteFunction()` can be simplified as follows

```
template <typename T>
void ExecuteFunction (getFuncType_t<T> f)
{
}
```

Comment: amazing, just what i needed.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, `void` in parentheses is but a vintage C-style sugar. You'll have to specialize your template:

```
template<> void Test::ExecuteFunction<void>(std::function<void()> f) {}
```

If that does not compile, well, you can use a helper template to encapsulate the type-selection:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class T> struct callable {
    using type = std::function<void(T)>;
};
template<class T> using callable_t =
    typename callable<T>::type;
template<> struct callable<void> {
    using type = std::function<void()>;
};

class Test
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void ExecuteFunction(callable_t<T> f) {}
};

int main() {
    Test test;

    test.ExecuteFunction<void>(    // does compile
                    [](void)->void {});

    test.ExecuteFunction<int>(    // this compiles
                    [](int)->void {});
}
```

But be aware that this way you'll have to also do something to the arguments passing (in your example, a generic case's argument is unary yet specialization for `void` expects a nullary function object).

Comment: Kinda have to specialize that member any way, since the primary cannot be naively written to work with `void` (how is it supposed to conjure a "void value"?)

Comment: i am not sure, where i would add this line. it doesn't work if i put it right under the template function and i also tried to put it into a .cpp file without success.
could you elaborate where to put this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add an overload to the class like this:

```
// as before:
template<class T>
void ExecuteFunction(std::function<void(T)> f) {}

// new overload (not a template):
void ExecuteFunction(std::function<void()> f) {}
```

As you can't use type deduction anyhow, you can now explicitly call this function by not specifying any template parameter as follows.

```
Test test;

test.ExecuteFunction(
     [](void)->void
     {
     int i = 5;
     });
```

Comment: this solution solves my syntax errors which is great. however, my project is obviously more complicated than the example i gave and in the end this leads to a lot of code duplication which is not very desirable for me.i have a strange feeling in my gut that this is the only solution though so thanks a lot for that.